# How to convert the following String into an Array

Tags: php, string

```
Disk Space:50MB Data transfer:500MB Domains:1 Email Accounts:2
```

I need the required output in this format.

```
Disk Space:50MB
Data transfer:500MB
Domains:1
Email Accounts:2
```

Comment: what do you have and what exactly do you want?

Comment: what is the separator of one string

Comment: You can try preg_split or just regular preg_match function to do that.

Comment: from database i am getting the value for description like the above output in string format, now i want to break it as shown above

Comment: It cannot ne done, if you do not have a delimiter other than SPACE for your values, unless you can guarantee that there is no space character inside your values.

Comment: @GangaRaju - exactly as yunzen said you have to put a delimiter to separate the string. Store the value in database using any delimiter so that you can easily explode it while displaying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$str="Disk Space:50MB Data transfer:500MB Domains:1 Email Accounts:2";
$match=null;
preg_match_all('/[^\:]+\:[^\s]+/i',$str,$match);
print_r($match);
```

outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Disk Space:50MB
            [1] =>  Data transfer:500MB
            [2] =>  Domains:1
            [3] =>  Email Accounts:2
        )

)
```

This assumed that your string will be in `[name][colon][value][space]` format, where no [colon] in [name], and no [space] in [value].

Also, you may want to `trim` the matched result.

Comment: [RESPONSE] code = 200 description = Command completed successfully property[domaincheck][0] = 211 Domain name not available property[domainchecktime][0] = 0.238 property[domaincheck][1] = 211 Domain name not available property[domainchecktime][1] = 0.238 queuetime = 0 runtime = 0.251 EOF

Comment: just we need to display as the above format, can you please help me how to split

Comment: @GangaRaju You can just replace the `:` to `=` in the matched array.

Comment: @GangaRaju Like this: `foreach($match[0] as $val) echo str_replace(":","=",trim($val))."<br />";` This will output `Disk Space=50MB<br />Data Transfer=500MB<br />` etc.

Comment: i need to workout for the below example:
[RESPONSE] code = 200 description = Command completed successfully property[domaincheck][0] = 211 Domain name not available property[domainchecktime][0] = 0.238 property[domaincheck][1] = 211 Domain name not available property[domainchecktime][1] = 0.238 queuetime = 0 runtime = 0.251 EOF
can you please consider this.

Comment: @GangaRaju That would be almost impossible for me, as there's no significant delimiter between a value and its next name. You can open a new question to this though, since I'm actually not quite good at Regex.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
echo nl2br("text\r\n");
?>
```

Comment: OP wants it returned as an array not have it broken into different lines with HTML.